# Justify content does not seem to affect my flexbox children. Is it because of my height/width properties for one of my elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I have set up is a flexbox that contains 3 children: the previous button, a div that contains the slideshow, and the next button. I have the flexbox set to justify-content: center, but the arrows stick to the far sides of the flexbox instead of right next to the slide div on either side. There is a gap between each arrow and the slide that won't go away unless I make the browser window narrower so the flexbox doesn't have any extra room. Setting justify-content to center should be keeping them all together.

I'm having the same issue with the slide container as well. It is also a flexbox and contains 3 children: a title, the image, and numbers at the bottom. When I shrink the window, the slide image shrinks to fit, but the title and numbers both stay stuck to the top and bottom of the flexbox instead of clustered in the middle with the image.

I would like this to be dynamic so I won't have to adjust the CSS as much with media queries for a number of different breaking points.

Things I have tried:

- setting the margins to 0px for all children
- setting the padding to 0px for all children
- putting the buttons inside the slideshow container instead of the
  current parent and setting the slideshow container to flex
- every other option for justify-content (center, flex-start, flex-end, etc); none of them seemed to have any effect on the children
- removing the width attribute from my slideshow container and setting it to auto (this made the slides disappear)
  removing the height attribute from my slide container (this did fix the issue, but it also caused the slide to extend past the boundaries of its container)

I am also using some javascript that probably doesn't need to be included, but it sets each new slide's display to block and each previous slide's display to none. In order for this slideshow to work, I am under the impression that the slides need to their position set to absolute, and their parent container set to relative.

Here is a fiddle with the exact code I am using. I initially tried to simplify it to ask this question by removing container1 and the description on the left, but then I couldn't replicate the problem I was having. I am wondering if it has something to do with the height or width attributes of one of elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/kj7wzr5a/

```css
.container1 {
  width: 85%;
  height: 650px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.descrip1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
}


.slideshow-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 360px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.slide:first-child {display: block}

.slide {
   -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
   transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.slide img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */

.buttons {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1 bodytext">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="descrip1">
          <p>Blah blah text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="buttons">
            <a class="slider_nav prev">&#60;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow-container">
          <div class="slide">
            <div class="flex">
              <div class="text">New Character</div>
              <img src="1.png" style="width:100%">
              <div class="numbertext">1 / 10</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slide">
            <div class="flex">
              <div class="text">New Character Stats</div>
              <img src="2.png" style="width:100%">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <a class="slider_nav next">&#62;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am fairly new to coding and haven't had any formal training.